# onfocus and onblur does not work in content page in vb.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

here's my code -

```
function doFocus(text) {
        if (text.value == "FirstName") {
            text.value = "";
            text.style.color = "#444444";
        }
     )
function doBlurFName(text) {
        if (text.value == "") {
            text.value = "FirstName"
            text.style.color = "Gray";
            return;
        }
    }

asp:TextBox ID="tb_firstname" runat="server" Text="FirstName" CssClass="FormBox" onfocus="doFocus(this)" onblur="doBlurFName(this)"></asp:TextBox>
```

This is the content page which has a Master Page in the back. Whenever I run this i get the following error -
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected
I'm not sure why this error is coming up and also how to fix it.

Another thing is the dofocus and doblur works fine in the master page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine when I tested it, though I did notice a typo. Should be a close bracket.

[image]

Comment: that typo is when i put code here. Its } in the code in aspx page. Also you said it works fine on your system. Did you put it in the content page and NOT the master page. Cause I'm having problems with content page. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a syntax error. You have a parenthesis at the end of doFocus where you should have a curly brace